# Slow WRITE operations SQL Server, corrupt backup file after COPY

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am not a network type but a Programmer. I have been working with our DBA and Network technician about a problem I am experiencing. First, our DBA recently moved the database I support from one server to another. They are virtual machines but the move went across new physical servers as well. A RESTORE on the previous server took roughly 1 hour. The restore over to the new server took 5 hours. When a backup file is created on the new SQL Server, that backup file is copied over to another physical server. We are unable to use that backup file to restore. It gets an error RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. This happens once you select the backup file in the Restore Database dialog screen, before even clicking OK or selecting any options. This same backup file can be restored on the new server where it was created. So my theory is the WRITE performance on the new server is so bad that the copy over to another server is corrupting the file. I dont have any details of the hardware specs but does anyone have any places our network guys and DBA could start to troubleshoot. Any assistance would be awesome.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. 1. Are both SQL Servers 2008R2? 2. How fast are the disks on the old and new servers? I can't say for certain without this information, but my gut instinct is that yes, disk performance is awful on the new server, and perhaps the old server is 2008 rather than R2.  Also, these are good recommendations for Virtualized SQL Server.  http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/05/keys-deploying-sql-server-on-vmware/

Answer (score 1):

Bad write performance doesn't "corrupt files"-- it just makes writing slow. (No sane software is written w/ the attitude "Hey, thins are going slow so we'll just trash your data...")

It sounds, to me, like you have an underlying hardware problem that is corrupting writes. If I had to guess, I'd say it's causing your poor write performance, too. W/o knowing more about the storage subsystem, though, I can't say anything.

Comment: What Evan said.  Ask them to see if the new server is, perhaps, RAID 5 with a dead disk in it.  (Wild guess.)

Comment: Probably not a bad guess. That, or some brain-damaged RAID controller w/o no write cache... (*cough*  Dell H300  *cough*)